# macOS Catalina on AWS: merging partitions

Tags: mac, aws

I have created a macOS Catalina EC2 instance on AWS with an EBS volume size of 60 GB.
Then I resized the volume on AWS to 120 GB and tried the following commands to resize the APFS container accordingly:

```
PDISK=$(diskutil list physical external | head -n1 | cut -d" " -f1)
APFSCONT=$(diskutil list physical external | grep "Apple_APFS" | tr -s " " | cut -d" " -f8)
yes | sudo diskutil repairDisk $PDISK
sudo diskutil apfs resizeContainer $APFSCONT 0
```

Unfortunately the last command gives me the following output:

> Started APFS operation Error: -69743: The new size must be different
> than the existing size

That's the output of "diskutil list":

[image: Output of diskutil list on my macOS instance]

I am not sure about what's happening, but I am wondering, would it be possible to merge disk1 and disk0 into one disk? Without breaking the system, and where I could install applications as "normal".

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because It is not about Apple hardware and *seems* to be about running macOS on Amazon's cloud, which is (essentially) hackintosh, which (I believe) is considered off-topic.

Comment: AWS EC2 Mac instances are within licensing… but other than that I've no idea how they work.

Comment: @SteveChambers, it's not considered as "hackintosh" as it is officially supported by AWS and Apple. Reference: https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/mac/

Comment: I've cleared the close votes on this being a hackintosh question, the question is on-topic as far as licensing is concerned.

Comment: @nohillside noted and thank you. Learn something new every day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: I had to restart the EC2 instance and the command then worked.